# How to check for alphanumeric characters in a binary file

Tags: python

I'm a beginner trying to write a program that will read in .exe files, .class files, or .pyc files and get the percentage of alphanumeric characters (a-z,A-Z,0-9).  Here's what I have right now (I'm just trying to see if I can identify anything at the moment, not looking to count stuff yet):

```
chars_total = 0
chars_alphnum = 0
iterate = 1

with open("pythonfile.pyc", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(iterate)
    while byte != b"":

        chars_total += 1
        print (byte)

        iterate +=1
        byte = f.read(iterate)
```

This code prints out various bytes such as

```
b'\xe1WQ\x00'
b'\x00\x00c\x00\x00'
```

but I'm having trouble with translating the bytes themselves.

I've also tried `print (binascii.hexlify(byte))` after importing binascii which converts everything into alphanumeric characters, which seems to not quite be what I'm looking for.  So am I just getting something severely mistaken or am I at least on the right track?

Full disclaimer, this is related in small part to a homework assignment, but we have permission to use this site because neither the in class material nor the reading covers any coding at all.  And yes, I have been trying to figure this out before I came on here.

Comment: you really have to do your homework.

Comment: 1) Open the file. 2) Read its contents. 3) Iterate over the bytes. 4) Determine if a byte is alphanumeric or not. 5) Keep count. 6) Display result. So far you've shown that you've done none of these steps. Please indicate what specifically you're having trouble with, and show the code where you've at least attempted.

Comment: Yes, this is part of a homework assignment.  See the edits above.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are reading from an arbitrary binary for which it might not be possible to decode it to ASCII/UTF-8, you could try something like the following

```
import string
# create a set of the ascii code points for alphanumerics
alphanumeric_codes = {ord(c) for c in string.ascii_letters + string.digits}
file_bytes = b'...'
alphanumerics = (b for b in file_bytes if b in alphanumeric_codes)
percent_alphanumerics = 100.0 * len(alphanumerics) / len(filebytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you could use a simple PowerShell script to get the hexdump (take a look here http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/get-hex-dumps-files-powershell) and then, decode it to whatever standard you want (ascii, unicode) with Python (take a look here https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr), keeping only the alphanumeric characters.

On Linux, *$man hexdump* on a terminal.